# Goal: How to handle the uni codes present in the file name

Tags: unicode

**My goal is to handle the Unicode characters present in the file name, such that the uni code gets replaced by an underscore. Any help would be deeply appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'c' ':' '\' 'p' 'r' 'o' 'g' and so on are all Unicode characters - they just happen to have code points less that 127.

Given that all the characters in the file name will be Unicode, find the number of characters of the file name and create a string consisting of that number of underscores.

Comment: @Jithin maybe ask a new question which actually says what you're trying to achieve, such as 'I want to replace all Unicode characters in a string above codepoint 127 with underscores using Java' or whatever your actual requirements are.